# Create link between data in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, graph-theory

I have the following data :

```
Source Target
A1  B1
A2  B1
A3  B1
A1  B2
A2  B2
A3  B2
A1  B3
A2  B3
A3  B3
A1  B4
A2  B4
```

Basically, it means that B1, B2 and B3 depends on A1,A2 and A3. B4 depends only on A1,A2.
I export those data into a graph, to draw the relation between the data and have a visual representation easier to analyse. As you can guess, this creates a lot of lines, and the graph is not really lisible.
I would like to regroup them by creating an intermediate data (Cx) : for each target which have the same sources as another target, Cx is created.
This would give :

```
A1 C1
A2 C1
A3 C1
C1 B1
C1 B1
C1 B1
A1 C2
A2 C2
C2 B4
```

This way, in the graph, A1, A2 and A3 will be link to C1 and C1 will be link to B1,B2,B3.
A1 and A2 will be link to C2, and C2 to B4
This allows to avoid lines overcrossing each others.

I tried creating Cx by using listagg, without success.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a collection:

```sql
CREATE TYPE item_list AS TABLE OF CHAR(2);
```

and then use it to aggregate once to collate the sources and then aggregate a second time to collate the targets and assign the link values and then you can unpack the aggregated values:

```sql
WITH links ( sources, targets, link ) AS (
  SELECT sources,
         targets,
         'C' || ROWNUM
  FROM   (
    SELECT sources,
           CAST( COLLECT( target ) AS item_list ) AS targets
    FROM   (
      SELECT LISTAGG( source, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY source ) AS sources,
             target
      FROM   table_name
      GROUP BY target
    )
    GROUP BY sources
  )
)
SELECT l.link AS source,
       t.COLUMN_VALUE AS target
FROM   links l
       CROSS JOIN TABLE( l.targets ) t
UNION ALL
SELECT s.COLUMN_VALUE,
       l.link
FROM   links l
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( l.sources, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( l.sources, '[^,]+' )
           )
           AS item_list
         )
       ) s
```

*(Note: trying to `GROUP BY` a column containing a collection data type was raising an exception so to avoid this the aggregation at the first stage was done using `LISTAGG` and then reversed with a correlated hierarchical query in a table collection expression. It would have been much simpler to use `CAST`/`COLLECT` for both aggregations but this did not appear to be possible.)*

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( source, target ) AS
SELECT 'A1', 'B1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'B1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 'B1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', 'B2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'B2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 'B2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', 'B3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'B3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 'B3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', 'B4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'B4' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> SOURCE | TARGET
> :----- | :-----
> C1     | B4    
> C2     | B1    
> C2     | B3    
> C2     | B2    
> A1     | C1    
> A2     | C1    
> A1     | C2    
> A2     | C2    
> A3     | C2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cf3dd54fc62b13c2ee3596eab3fcb55c)*

Answer (score 0):

You can get the target values that share all the same sources by using:

```
select sources, target, 
       dense_rank() over (order by sources) as c_number
from (select target, listagg(source, ',') within group (order by source) as sources
      from t
      group by target
     ) t;
```

I'm not sure if this is sufficient for what you are asking.  This provides the groupings.

Comment: This gives the link between C1 and B1/B2/B3 and between C2 and B4. Now I need to adapt this to have the link between A1/A2/A3 and C1 and between A1/A2 and C2

Comment: This seems to work. I'll check tomorrow:

select 'TARGET',sources, target,
       dense_rank() over (order by sources) as c_number
from (
select target, listagg(source, ',') within group (order by source) as sources
      from datas
      group by target
      )
union
select 'SOURCE',sources, source, 
       dense_rank() over (order by sources) as c_number
from (
select source, listagg(source, ',') within group (order by source) over (partition by target) as sources
      from datas
      )